# Listview with progressbar which is updated using Asynctask

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I am using a Listview with progressbar to show the downloading of file using Asynctask. There is a button to add rows each row is having a progress bar and over the progress bar I have given textviews to show time taking for download and the data transferred. The problem is when I scroll listview , the progress showing on ProgressBar disappears and time and data transfer stops updating, but the downloading file is happening. If more rows are there and I scroll the Listview it will crash . Anybody has idea on this please help...

Comment: Post the code of your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```